# What is difference between a node with ns and node inside group with same namespace?

Tags: ros, namespace, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A node in ROS can have ns as an attribute that starts node in given namespace.

A node also be grouped inside a namespace by nesting it under group tag.

But is different in both scenario.

For me both types of code are giving different behavior:

Type 1:

```
<node name="controller_spawner$(arg robot_name)" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
output="screen" ns="/$(arg robot_name)" args="joint1_velocity_controller joint2_velocity_controller                                  front_left_steering_position_controller front_right_steering_position_controller  joint_state_controller"/>
```

Type 2:

```
 <group="$(arg robot_name)">
    <node name="controller_spawner$(arg robot_name)" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
    output="screen" args="joint1_velocity_controller joint2_velocity_controller                                  front_left_steering_position_controller front_right_steering_position_controller  joint_state_controller"/>
</group>
```

Type 1 runs successfully and I get console output as:

```
Started controllers: joint1_velocity_controller, joint2_velocity_controller, front_left_steering_position_controller, front_right_steering_position_controller, joint_state_controller
```

Type 2 fails I get following output in console:

```
Controller Spawner couldn't find the expected controller_manager ROS interface.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249250/what-is-difference-between-a-node-with-ns-and-node-inside-group-with-same-namespace?/) by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2016-12-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-02**:
It would be nice if you could tell us what "different behaviour" you have observed, specifically.

**Comment by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on 2016-12-02**:
Without context, it is hard to tell but I am editing question to make it more understandable.

**Comment by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on 2016-12-02**:
Thanks for pointing this out. It solved the issue. I will add a reply to this answer myself.
Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like one of them is absolute (`/..`), while the other is relative (no `/`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on 2016-12-02**:
I found out that there is no difference in both syntax.  As @gvdhoorn pointed out, I had made a mistake and one of them is absolute (/..), while the other is relative (no /).